# Help in finding a function in $L^p$ such that $f*g=||g||_1 f$ with $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ non negative and fixed

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution

I consider a non negative function $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

I want to find a function $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$ f*g=||g||_1 \:f ,$$ where $*$ is the convolution.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me finding this function $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Albeit not too interesting, $f \equiv 0$ works.

If the space is a probability space, $p \geq 1\,^\dagger$ and $ \|g\|_1 \neq 0$, then $h:= \frac{g}{\|g\|_1}$ is a probability density (let's say of a rnd. var. $X$) and your equation becomes:
$$f * h = f$$
Now if $f$ is a probabilty density of $Y$, then $f*h$ is the PDF of  $X+Y$.
And the above equation says that $X+Y = Y$ with a probability of $1$.
This means that $X = 0$ with a probablity of $1$. So indeed $f=0$ a.e.

$^\dagger$ see [stochasticboy321](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269063/stochasticboy321)'s comment below.

Comment: Clever. However, note that this only holds for $p\ge 1$, since a function in $L^p$ need not be normalisable if $p<1$, and so $f$ may not be the pdf of any $Y$ in such a case.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Yes, thank you for pointing that out! Edited my answer accordingly.